# Crash on glDrawArrays with glVertexAttrib3f

Tags: iphone, c++, opengl-es-2.0

I saw quite a few other posts related to EXC_BAD_ACCESS signals right on glDrawArrays, but none quite fit my problem, so here it goes.

The following code works:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(mAttributes.position);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(mAttributes.color);

GLsizei stride = sizeof(Vertex);
const GLvoid* pPos = &mVertices2[0].mPos.x;
const GLvoid* pColors = &mVertices2[0].mColor.r;

glVertexAttribPointer(mAttributes.position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, pPos);
glVertexAttribPointer(mAttributes.color, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, pColors);

glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, mVertices2.size());
```

But I can't seem to write to color with a constant attribute. This crashes on glDrawArrays:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(mAttributes.position);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(mAttributes.color);

glVertexAttribPointer(mAttributes.position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, stride, pPos);
glVertexAttrib3f(mAttributes.color, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, mVertices2.size()); // <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS because of the line above
```

Does anyone know why? Can you only use the constant vertex attribute calls with `glDrawElements`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you are telling OpenGL to use a VertexAttribArray, and then you do not provide the array elements. Consequently, OpenGL will try to read memory which is neither allocated nor properly filled. Be sure to do a

```
glDisableVertexAttribArray(ARRAYINDEX)
```

when you do not provide the data for a specific array . Using just `glVertexAttrib3f()` is ok. But it is not an array, so you don't need to enable arrays to use it.

Comment: Ah, of course, that slipped right by me.  Thanks for the quick answer, I was staring at this one and getting no where.